# Modifying Bellman-Ford to support a second edge weight

Tags: c++, algorithm, bellman-ford

So given the initial and final nodes, I need to use the Bellman-Ford alg to:

1. Find a path with the lowest cost while
2. Remaining under a specific time duration

Each edge has cost and time/duration weights.

I can't figure out how to optimize this however, maybe with a priority queue? Would I alter the relax function or the entire program?

Comment: In the [relaxation step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Algorithm), look at the predecesors and adjust the distance to infinite again when the total predecessors' time is over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a slight modification to Bellman-Ford.
As usual the outer loop will run for atmost N-1 times where N is number of vertices.

Instead of storing the distance to a vertex from the source, you will have to store both distance and time for each vertex. (denoted by `dist` and `time` below)

The inner loop will be slightly modified:-

1. Iterate over all the vertices.
2. For each vertex v, iterate over its neighbours.
3. For each neighbour u: (Tmax is the maximum time allowed)

   ```
   if (dist[v] + cost_of_edge[v -> u] < dist[u]) then
       if (time[v] + time_of_edge[v -> u] < Tmax) then
           dist[u] = dist[v] + cost_of_edge[v -> u]
           time[u] = time[v] + time_of_edge[v -> u]
       end if
   end if
   else if (dist[v] + cost_of_edge[v -> u] == dist[u]) then
        if (time[v] + time_of_edge[v -> u] < time[u]) then
            time[u] = time[v] + time_of_edge[v -> u]
        end if
   end if
   ```

The first if condition is just like normal Bellman - Ford: trying to find minimum distance to `u`, at the same time ensuring the time taken to reach `u` is not more than Tmax.

The second if condition is new: Let's say there is a path `P` from source to `u` with cost `dist[u]` and takes time `time[u]` to be traversed. Now let's say we find another path `P'` which has the same cost `dist[u]` but takes lesser time than `time[u]` - we want to then choose this path because this will allow us to reach more vertices from `u`.

Let's say we don't choose the path `P'` but choose `P` instead, in that case, further in the algorithm, there maybe a path from `u` to another vertex, say `x`, which we cannot consider due to time constraints. But it maybe possible to consider this path if the path `P'` is chosen since time taken to traverse `P'` < time taken to traverse `P`.

Comment: I have a couple questions, what does the second code fragment mean? Do I run both?

Comment: Hello, yes, both code fragments will have to be run (I have edited my answer to make this obvious). I have also added an explanation of my algorithm. Feel free to ask for further clarification.